# tx6s usbotg device-tree changing on it's own

Tags: linux, usb, device-tree

I have a tx6s-8035 SoC which we integrated into a custom board. We connected an Asix 88772B to the usbotg port and we need it to start in host mode.

We grounded the USBOTG_ID pin and we tought it will start in host mode. It didn't happen unfortunately.

I have investigated the issue and I see a strange behaviour... I wrote `dr_mode = host` as an extra property into the official device-tree. After that I modified the **ci_hdrc_imx** driver to print what it got in the device_node and it said "peripheral". I backtraced the problem and when the `of_usb_get_dr_mode()` function is being invoked the device-tree already contains `dr_mode = peripheral`.

Any ideas? I just can't imagine what happens there...

p.s.: I double-checked that I'm updating the device-tree in a proper manner.

Comment: I'm using KARO-TX6-2015-08-24 tag from the official git repository with factory configuration and device-tree. (except the property I mentioned above)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue:

The u-boot overrides the 'dr_mode' property with it's 'usbotg' parameter so I had to change the environment variable in u-boot and it works since that.

Maybe it helps others too.